# JAX-RS API Fault Response into java

Tags: java, api, rest, jax-rs

I am accessing an API which is returning 404 error with a Fault message. I want to use the exact message in my java code. I am not sure how to access it.

Normal response comes in  element

But this is coming in form of Fault and I want to access the message inside it. Kindly suggest which class to use for it. Or any sample code snippents.

Below is the sample responses in different format.

XML Response:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://abc.cu.ms/api/resource">
   <Message>Service not found</Message>
</Fault>
```

JSON:

```
{"Message": "Service not found"}
```

RAW:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 09:30:38 GMT
Content-Length: 37

{"Message":"Service not found"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever JAX-RS implementation you are using, it should have a client API. If you using a JAX-RS 2 implementation, there should be a standard Client API. If you are using a JAX-RS 1 implementation, then the Client API will be specific to the implementation (and you will probably need to import a jar dependencies).

For a JAX-RS 2 implementation, you could do something like this

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
Fault fault = response.readEntity(Fault.class);
String message = fault.getMessage();
```

Your `Fault` class can simple look something like

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Fault")
public class Fault {
    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    } 
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

For the namespace in the xml, you can simply add a `package-info.java` file the package the `Fault` class is in. It would look like

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.org/package",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 

package thepackage.of.your.fault.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

You can read more about namespaces [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html).

For more information specific to your implementation, please provide more information as to what JAX-RS implementation you are using

For JSON, you might need to add/register a provider, but again I would need to know what implementation you're working with to help with that.

Comment: You are right! I am new to this thing. Went through all tutorials and am clear now. Your comments helpfull. Thanks!